# Using Nav2 with external localization source

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use Nav2 to navigate my robot from its current location to a waypoint or set of waypoints.
I have an external localization computer that computes the exact location and provides the tf of map->odom->base_link to ros2.
I launched the nav2_bringup with amcl and I can see my robot in RViz with no issues. I then tried to run the navigate_to_waypoint example from the nav2_simple_commander navigation package but I always get the following error:

```
[INFO] [1668174934.714896959] [basic_navigator]: Setting initial pose 
 [INFO] [1668174934.715584247] [basic_navigator]: Publishing Initial Pose 
 [INFO] [1668174934.716242568] [basic_navigator]: Waiting for amcl_pose to be received.
```

I also get the following in the nav2_bringup window:

```
[component_container_isolated-3] [INFO] [1668174656.886551258] [amcl]: Setting pose (1668174656.886551): 3.450 2.150 3.142
```

Is there anything I am missing. How can I use Nav2 to for navigation without using its internal localization.

I am using ROS2 Humble

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409260/using-nav2-with-external-localization-source/) by [mamado](https://answers.ros.org/users/65803/mamado/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2022-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nav2 has no problem using any localizer you choose. If it provides the map to odom transformation, the rest of the system doesn't care which is used.

From `[basic_navigator]`, that look to me like you're using the Simple Commander API. We wait for the pose to be received in the `waitUntilNav2Active` function: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/987fe905ec58a97ec85c485a1733ead585a5bc7f/nav2_simple_commander/nav2_simple_commander/robot_navigator.py#L311-L318

As you can see from the signature, you can specify the localizer node's name being used. Only when this is set to AMCL will this wait for that topic to receive a pose. Otherwise, it does not.

```
def waitUntilNav2Active(self, navigator='bt_navigator', localizer='amcl'):
    """Block until the full navigation system is up and running."""
    self._waitForNodeToActivate(localizer)
    if localizer == 'amcl':
        self._waitForInitialPose()
    self._waitForNodeToActivate(navigator)
    self.info('Nav2 is ready for use!')
    return
```

It just looks to me like you need to specify your localization node to wait for activation correctly. This is also specified in the Nav2 documentation on the API https://navigation.ros.org/commander_api/index.html

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-11-13**:
@mamado if you are running your own external global localization, you shouldn't be using AMCL at the same time. Having two ros nodes publishing the `map->odom` TF is going to lead to unstable localization.